# TeamCity Visual Studio Plugin

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, teamcity

We use TeamCity at work.  It would be nice to be able to keep an eye on checkin, build, and test run status without having to have a browser window open.

I have seen references to a TeamCity Visual Studio plugin **[here](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2010/09/20/vs_addin_resharper/)** and **[here](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/download/index.html)**.  The second page is their Professional vs. Enterprise Edition feature comparison page.  Both version list "Plugins for MS Visual Studio, Eclipse, and JetBrains IDEs family."

Does anyone know how to download and install this add-in?  It does not appear to be in the general TeamCity installation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

On your TeamCity web UI, goto `My Settings and Tools`

On the `TeamCity tools` right sidebar, you will see a link to download the Visual Studio Addin.

Direct link:  http://your.teamcity.server/update/vsAddinInstallerv4.msi

Comment: Absolutely correct.  Thanks for being the first response, and for having the exact right answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
wget https://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/JetBrains.ReSharperUltimate.LightInstaller.exe
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)